# Azure API for granting service principle access to a subscription?

Tags: python, azure, azure-resource-manager, service-principal

Is there is an Azure API available that would allow me to do the steps outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role

The closest thing I can find is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments

I use the Python SDK, the interface to that API is here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/azure-mgmt-authorization

This API seems to be for granting access to resources under an Azure subscription, not to the subscription itself...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, The REST API [`Role Assignments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments) and the API [`create(scope, role_assignment_name, properties=None, custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config)`](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.authorization.operations.html#azure.mgmt.authorization.operations.RoleAssignmentsOperations.create) of `azure-mgmt-authorization` in Azure Python SDk are you want. Please notes the `scope` property/argument in the APis which has many different formats for different scopes as below. For example, you need to use use `/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/` for a subscription.

> **scope** (str) – The scope of the role assignment to create. The scope can be any REST resource instance. For example, use ‘/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/’ for a subscription, ‘/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}’ for a resource group, and ‘/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/{resource-provider}/{resource-type}/{resource-name}’ for a resource.

Hope it helps.